# Reliable django-river alternatives?

Tags: django, workflow, django-river

I like the workflow functionality that [django-river](https://django-river.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides, but its performance is inappropriate and occasionally it fails to find the next available choices.

Do you know any fast and reliable django-river alternatives that would use Python code instead of database relations for workflow states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need also these alternatives and I found this [site](https://number1.co.za/django-moderation-workflow-tools-reviewed/)
I think there are reliable alternatives. You check it out

In short:

- **django-moderation** – a reusable application for Django framework, that allows to moderate any model objects [204 Stars]
- **activflow** – a generic, light-weight & extensible Workflow Engine for agile automation of Business Processes [343 Stars]
- **viewflow** – Reusable workflow library [942 Stars]
- **SpiffWorkflow** – A powerful workflow engine implemented in pure Python [539 Stars]
- **django-river** – Django workflow library supports on the fly changes [322 Stars]
- **django-fsm** – Django friendly finite state machine support [972 Stars]